# Vue.component construction raised error untill ".default" key was added

Tags: vuejs2

In  @vue/cli 4 and vuejs 2.6.10 app, trying to use component with command :

```
Vue.component('listing-header', require('../../../src/components/ListingHeader.vue'))
```

I got console error :

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

After search on the net, I found that it can be fixed with :

```
Vue.component('listing-header', require('../../../src/components/ListingHeader.vue').default)
```

I wonder what “.default” is here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Webpack's [dynamic imports documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)

> The reason we need `default` is that since webpack 4, when importing a CommonJS module, the import will no longer resolve to the value of module.exports, it will instead create an artificial namespace object for the CommonJS module.

`import()` promise resolve is an object containing module's exports as keys. By using `.default` you are accessing module's default export....